# How to assign s a FMX.TImage to a VCL.TBitmap?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I try to do this:

```
BMP.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
```

Image1 is a FMX object.
BMP is a standard (VCL.Graphics) bitmap.

The error I get is:

```
Project Project1.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message
'Cannot assign a TBitmapOfItem to a TBitmap'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign an FMX `TBitmap` to a VCL `TBitmap`. They are not compatible with each other (you shouldn't even be mixing VCL and FMX in the same project to begin with, they are not designed to be used together).

You will have to save the FMX `TBitmap` to a BMP-formatted stream/file and then load that into the VCL `TBitmap`.

Using a file is straight forward:

```
Image1.Bitmap.SaveToFile('file.bmp');
BMP.LoadFromFile('file.bmp');
```

However, when using a stream instead, FMX's `TBitmap.SaveToStream()` saves in PNG format only, so you have to use `TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream()` to save in BMP format, eg:

```
Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Surface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    Surface.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
    TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(Strm, Surface, '.bmp');
  finally
    Surface.Free;
  end;
  Strm.Position := 0;
  BMP.LoadFromStream(Strm);
finally
  Strm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Wow. That is nasty! I need to pass the bmp to windows api. Looks like FMX was not designed to interact with MS Windows OS. Converting the bitmap to png and back to bmp is going to be slower that what I need!

Comment: @Ampere you don't need to use VCL to interact with the Win32 API in FMX. Just call API functions directly, like any other function, and wrap the calls in `IFDEF` if you are making a cross-platform app. The code I showed in my answer is not converting a PNG to BMP, it is showing what you have to do to save directly in BMP and *avoid* saving in PNG (why Embarcadero didn't add an optional extension parameter to `TBitmap.SaveToStream()` is anyone's guess, considering `TBitmap.SaveToFile()` is extension-aware)